# set custom width to columns below colspan row

Tags: html, css

I have a table with fixed thead and tfoot, I'm using rowspawn and colspan on thead.

Is there a way so set custom width to the columns below COL 7 (COL 7-1, COL 7-2 and COL 7-3)? I've tried a lot of things but I can't figure out how to solve this.

As you can see using style="width" on these columns doesn't help.

```css
tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}

thead,
tfoot {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.cap {
  width: 30.085%;
  text-align: right !important;
}

thead,
tfoot {
  width: calc(100% - 17px);
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  padding-right: 17px;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 99%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.contenedor {
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.cuerpo80 {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  margin: 10px auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.numerico {
  text-align: right !important;
}

.string {
  text-align: left !important;
}

.stringSO {
  text-align: left !important;
}

table.cuerpoTabla {
  border-spacing: 1;
  font-family: Arial, 'Arial Unicode MS', sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #2D396C;
}

table.cuerpoTabla thead th,
table.cuerpoTabla tfoot th {
  text-align: center;
  background: #96A8B9;
  border: 1px solid #446380;
  height: 25px;
}

table.cuerpoTabla thead th {
  padding: 0px 4px;
}

table.cuerpoTabla tfoot th {
  padding: 2px 10px 0;
}

table.cuerpoTabla thead tr:first-child th:first-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
}

table.cuerpoTabla thead tr:first-child th:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
}

table.cuerpoTabla thead tr:first-child th:only-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

table.cuerpoTabla tbody th,
table.filtrosTabla tbody td {
  margin: 3px;
  min-height: 25px;
}

table.cuerpoTabla tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: #E5EDFA;
}

.complete_td {
  padding: 2px 10px 0 !important;
  text-align: left !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.subtotal td:first-child {
  font-weight: bold !important;
  text-align: right !important;
}

table.cuerpoTabla tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: #FFF;
}

table.cuerpoTabla tbody tr:not(.nohover):hover td {
  background: #EFBF50 !important;
  color: #405989;
}

table.cuerpoTabla tbody td {
  background: #EBEEF1;
  height: 25px !important;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

table.cuerpoTabla tbody td:first-child:not([colspan]) {
  text-align: center;
  background: #96A8B9 !important;
  border: 1px solid #446380;
  height: 25px;
  width: 2%;
}

table.cuerpoTabla tbody td:first-child {
  background: #96A8B9 !important;
  border: 1px solid #446380;
  height: 25px;
}

table.cuerpoTabla tfoot tr:last-child th:first-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 4px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 4px;
}

table.cuerpoTabla tfoot tr:last-child th:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 0;
}

table.cuerpoTabla tfoot th:only-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="contenedor">

    <div class="cuerpo80">

      <div>

        <table class="cuerpoTabla" style="min-width: 1393px">

          <thead>

            <tr>

              <th style="width: 3%;" rowspan="2">COL 1</th>
              <th style="width: auto;" rowspan="2">COL 2</th>
              <th style="width: 9%;" rowspan="2">COL 3</th>
              <th style="width: 6%;" rowspan="2">COL 4</th>
              <th style="width: 9%;" rowspan="2">COL 5</th>
              <th style="width: 6%;" rowspan="2">COL 6</th>
              <th style="width: 20%;" colspan="3">COL 7</th>
              <th style="width: 6%;" rowspan="2">COL 8</th>
              <th style="width: 7%;" rowspan="2">COL 9</th>

            </tr>

            <tr>

              <th style="width: 48%;">COL 7-1</th>
              <th style="width: 48%;">COL 7-2</th>
              <th style="width: 4%;">COL 7-3</th>

            </tr>

          </thead>

          <tbody>
          </tbody>

          <tfoot>
          </tfoot>

        </table>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As they take their lead from the row - and cell widths - above, the best way is to nest a table within your second row (COL 7-1 etc)

An example: https://codepen.io/blueocto/pen/jzVBWz

You can see the width's are being applied.

```
<th style="width: 20%;" colspan="3">
COL 7
<table>
<tr>
<th style="width: 48%;">COL 7-1</th>
<th style="width: 48%;">COL 7-2</th>
<th style="width: 4%;">COL 7-3</th>
</tr>
</table>
</th>
```

*If my answer did help solve your issue, I'd really appreciate the upvote, thank you.*